# htaccess URL rewrite isn't working with hyphens

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've got some fantastic code for rewriting some URLs with `.htaccess`. And it works great.

However, it seems like the URL doesn't accept hyphens.

```
RewriteRule ^/?company/(\w+)/?$ /company-page.php?pURL=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?company/(\w+)/(\d+)/?$ /company-page.php?pURL=$1&page=$2 [END]
```

I've tried putting in a couple of regex switches using references online, but I'm completely baffled.

Here's the URL that works, and works fantastic:

```
https://www.example.com/company/leapdifferent/
```

But with hyphens in the business name, the page returns a 404. For example:

```
https://www.example.com/company/bds-dcor-prefab-pltd-21733
```

In short, I'm in an absolute pickle trying to modify my current regex to accept hyphens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/?company/(\w+)/?$ /company-page.php?pURL=$1 [END]
> ```

The `\w` shorthand character class does not include hyphens. Specifically, this matches `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_` (underscore).

To match hyphens as well as the above, then change the regex sub pattern `\w` to `[\w-]`, a character class that now includes hyphens.